# How do I run multiple instances war in one Liberty Server?

Tags: war, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have an application running as war in Liberty Server. How do I have the multiple instances of the same run in Liberty Server? Is there a way to get the name of the war  inside the java code?

String completePath=getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();

returned .../target/classes. No war file name.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify multiple `<webApplication ...>` elements in the server.xml with different values for the "id", "name" and "contextRoot" attributes, but specify the same "location" attribute (pointing to the actual WAR file).

As for getting the name of the WAR from the Java code, you could try using the `ServletContext` APIs like `getServletContextName()` or `getContextPath()` to differentiate between the multiple instances. More info in the javadoc here: https://www.openliberty.io/docs/20.0.0.10/reference/javadoc/liberty-javaee8-javadoc.html#javax/servlet/package-summary.html&class=javax/servlet/ServletContext.html&package=allclasses-frame.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have a total of four instances specified in server.xml. The console log shows four instances were started on my laptop. Now the app is deployed to Linux server with the exact same configuration. console.log only shows two instances running, no other errors. I've restarted the Liberty Server several times, still the same symptom. What could be the cause of the "partial" multi-thread?

Comment: My first thought is that maybe the location paths are wrong - maybe using backslashes instead of slashes or something like that. Be sure to check the messages.log file - it usually has more info than the console log. If you still have no luck, you may need to open a GitHub issue or support case. HTH

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! Yes, messages.log showed more info.

Comment: [11/18/20 10:52:08:012 PST] 00000034 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction 145" at ffdc_20.11.18_10.52.07.0.log

[11/18/20 10:52:08:032 PST] 00000034 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      E CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application myApp2. The exception message was: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: That sounds like a bug. You may want to open an issue here: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues - the more details you can provide in the issue, the better.

Comment: ffdc_20.11.18_10.52.07.0.log shows lots of exceptions that hard to figure out interpret. I searched web for CWWKZ0002E, https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/message-cwwkz0002e-occurs-ibm-websphere-application-server-was-liberty-v855. The ibm site suggested UTF-26 encoded in web.xml, but myApp doesn't use web.xml.

Comment: Thanks, Andy! I opened an issue. https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/15042